# Java multithreaded getters and setters

Tags: java, multithreading, static, volatile

Suppose I have a instance variable and I have setters and getters.

Code 1:

```
Class<T> {
    volatile T value;

    public synchronized void set(T v) {
        if(value==null) {
            value=v;
        }

    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
Class<T> {
    static volatile T value;

    public synchronized void set(T v) {
        if(value==null) {
            value=v;
        }
    }

    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have two questions

1) What is the difference having static volatile state field and only volatile state field?

2) I just came to know about  release / acquire concept of volatile read/write and  understood that there is no need to synchronize the getter(because of cache flush).But is there any need to synchronize the setter?

Comment: the answer to your first question is unrelated to multithreading - a static variable is a static variable. Whether the variable is volatile or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @assylias no, consider this: `class X implements Runnable { private static Object o; public void run() { o = new Object(); }}`. In this case it matters if the variable is static or not.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I did not say that static had no use, I only said that the meaning of the `static` keyword was the same for a non volatile and a volatile variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your second question:

I think the reason why you schould use a synchronized block in your setter is that you perform **two different operations** on `value`. You check `value==null` and afterwards you set `value=v`. While you do have the lock in each step you don't have it between them. So this is possible:

```
Thread1: lock value -> value==null (true) -> release value
Thread2: lock value -> value==null (true) -> release value
Thread1: lock value -> value=v -> release value;
Thread2: lock value -> value=v -> release value;
```

So you still have a race condition.

Now back to your first question: You schould use static to have any instance of your class use the same variable T instead of having an own one.

Answer (score -2):

In code 2, the following is possible:

```
Thread1: calls set(X) on instance1
Thread1: value is null, entering inside if
Thread2: calls set(Y) on onstance2
Thread2: value is null, entering inside if
Thread2: setting value = Y
Thread1: setting value = X
```

The problem is that lock is acquired on instances of your class, not class itself. If you would change both `set` and `get` methods to `static`, then it would work fine again.